# How to fix "Invalid conversion from throwing function of type X to non-throwing function type Y" with Do-Try-Catch

Tags: swift, try-catch

I am getting the error: **Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(Either) -> Void'**

on the line after `do {`, `weatherApi.weather(with: weatherEndpoint) { (either) in`

```
class WeatherTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var cellViewModels = [WeatherCellViewModel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let weatherApi = WeatherAPIClient()
        let weatherEndpoint = WeatherEndpoint.fiveDayForecast(city: "Atlanta", country: "us")

        do {
            weatherApi.weather(with: weatherEndpoint) { (either) in
            switch either {
                case .value(let Weather):
                    print("Made it")
                    print(Weather)
                    let data = try Weather.map {
                        $0.weather.map {
                            WeatherCellViewModel(description: $0.description)
                        }
                    }
                    print("data")
                    print(data)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                case .error(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("weather endpoint error")
        }
    }
```

I added the do try catch after getting the same error originally and looking at the answers to similar problems, but it did not solve it. The try block is the critical part causing the error, where I am parsing my data for the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `do-catch` is currently outside of the closure that has the `try` statement in it.

You'll need to move the `do-catch` into the closure. The error is because `weather` is expecting a closure that doesn't throw but it's getting on that does.

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to throw from within the closure, which is not possible. so you need to place `do-catch` into the closure

Try this way:

```
    do {
          let data = try Weather.map {
                    $0.weather.map {
                        WeatherCellViewModel(description: $0.description)
             }
         }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
```